# Using the Bloomberg API for Python, how do you get the historical AUM for a fund's ticker?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bloomberg

I currently have the Bloomberg API for C++ and Python installed on my machine. I have written code which gets the historical closing price of a stock using the code:

```
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
import pandas as pd

mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
sids = mgr['GOOG']
df = sids.get_historical('PX_LAST', '12/1/2005', datetime.today())
```

Can someone tell me how to get the historical AUM of a given ticker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the field `FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS` with your required fund, e.g. `MABAX US Equity`. It works just the same as `PX_LAST` does for an equity security.